# how to pass parameter on redirect in yii

Tags: php, yii

I am using Yii framework for my project;

I am  redirecting page after success of insertion in  database to another controller using

> $this->redirect($this->createUrl('controller/action'));

During the redirection is it possible to pass any parameters just like in render,

> $this->render('selectRefiner', array('param' => $data)

Comment: I don't understand why people doesn't refer to documentation. And yiis documentation is top notch unlike other frameworks. Just send it as array where 1st element is controller action and rest are key value pairs which you can get as GET variables.

Comment: @itachi for me yii documentation not very clear

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try:

```
$this->redirect(array('controller/action', 'param1'=>'value1', 'param2'=>'value2',...))
```

[api yii 1](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#redirect-detail), [api yii 2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-controller.html#redirect()-detail)

Comment: It would be great if you can explain how to get this value in called action? Thanks.

Comment: You can get the value in action from - $_REQUEST OR $_GET.

Comment: ... or if you input them on parameters in called function - like this public function actionAction($param1, $param2, ... )

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
Yii::$app->response->redirect(['site/dashboard','id' => 1, 'var1' => 'test']);
```

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Actually i want to redirect to another model ...render function fine for redirect page for current model but i want to redirect one model to another ..

Answer (score 2):

You can only pass GET parameters in the Yii 2 `redirect()`. However, I had a similar situation and I resolved it by using Session storage.

Naturally, you can access current Session via `Yii::$app->session`. Here is an example of using it in two separate controller actions:

```
public function actionOne() {
    // Check if the Session is Open, and Open it if it isn't Open already
    if (!Yii::$app->session->getIsActive()) {
        Yii::$app->session->open();
    }
    Yii::$app->session['someParameter'] = 'Bool/String/Array...';
    Yii::$app->session->close();
    $this->redirect(['site/two']);
}

public function actionTwo() {
    if (isset(Yii::$app->session['someParameter']) {
       $param = Yii::$app->session['someParameter'];
    } else {
       $param = null;
    }
    $this->render('two', [
        'param' => $param
    ]);
}
```

So now you should be able to access `$param` inside the `two` view.

For more information, please refer to the official class documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To redirect into same action with the all parameters that already have this works for me.

```
$this->redirect($_PHP['SELF']);
```