# yii redirect with array

Tags: php, redirect, yii

```
$this->redirect(array($redirect, 'error' => $error, 'msg' => $msg, 'details' => $details));
```

How can we pass array as a parameter? 
I have tried during redirection.

Returning:

> Error 400 Your request is invalid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to pass array?

Comment: as per my requirement I have too many data to pass on, that's why

Comment: create a string separated with `&` instead of passing array.

Comment: I knew, but that is not a solution

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13717351/4248328

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717228/how-to-pass-parameter-on-redirect-in-yii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lots of tries I have found that , the array what I was passing is an associative array and passing with `GET` method, so while redirection if we seen in URL, associative array passing with every internal element of `$details` array, and same parameters are not listed at destination method, so the result will not found such a method.

Comment: Your explanation is not clear: please post a complete code example.

Comment: Not needed to post a code, as we can not pass array like that, so I have sent separate variable as a single params

Comment: Yes, you can pass asociative arrays in url with GET. The problem is that isn't possible giving complex datatypes using method redirect() with Yii (and Yii2). The problem is with Yii not with the GET method.

The method is founded. The returned error is: Invalid data received for parameter "{param}".

Answer (score 0):

If redirect to different page

```
$this->redirect(array('YourController/YourFunction','error'=>$error,'msg'=>$msg,'details'=>$details));
```

If in the same controller you just need to put your function on the array.
hope this can help

Comment: I have already tried, your answer is already in my question, see.